# What language can be compiled for both iOS and Android?

Tags: android, c++, ios, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I'm looking to develop an app for both iOS and Android, and I would like to be able to compile to both without having to actually write in two different languages.

GUI will be simple: buttons, drop down menus, textboxes. Although it would be a bonus to have these in a pre-made library or as part of the phone utils, I can and will write my own if needed. However, I will need access to phone hardware such as GPS and location, internet access, notifications, running in background and possibly vibration.

I'd like to program in C++ or similar in preference, but any language that will cross-compile should do. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** I'm asking about what frameworks I can use for this, and what languages they use.

Comment: The language and its compilation is not the big problem. There are very few similarities between the platforms, and you should look for a cross-platform framework.

Comment: Yeah Xamarin or Ionic depends of your preference

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of engines you could use. Xamarin is one of the bests(programms are written in c#)

Answer (score 2):

I know what you mean. Try Eqela. Check this out for a quick overview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcWf7SXGBv0

> Eqela, a programming language translator that enables software
>   developers to create software applications for several operating
>   systems using a single set of source code, makes it possible to deploy
>   applications on mobile, desktop and the web simultaneously. It is
>   based on application source code conversion technology.

The language is OOP so you will feel comfortable programming with it. Since it is based on source code conversion, the target source code is native to your target platform. Eqela can be translated to Android, iOS, and a lot of other popular platforms. HTML5 is also part of the target source code!

Access to your target platform's native code is also available. Let's say one of your target is Android, you could include Android-specific codes inside Eqela source code.

I've used this first hand and I think this is a great tool. However, since this is not popular language, community support is limited.

For more info:
http://eqdn.tech/

Comment: The Eqela language has recently gone through an upgrade: http://eqdn.tech/sling/

Answer (score 0):

Use Ionic(design) + Cordova. But you should know HTML, CSS and Javascript.